# Any header file to read text files platform-independent?

Tags: c++, file-io, cross-platform

Working on a cross-platform project in C++, which must read input files in a very simple format:

```
MESSAGE_NAME "Message text"
ANOTHER_GOOD_MESSAGE "This is another message"
```

...

I wonder if somebody has or knows a library (a header file) for handling inputs that may be in Windows format or Linux format.

Comment: Is there something wrong with standard IO streams?

Comment: the client doesn't use STL :/ Just C input methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with `#include <fstream>`?

Of course, it's conceivable that a Windows implementation would fail to
recognize Unix line endings (but I've yet to see one that doesn't), or
that a Unix implementation has problems with the extra `'\r'`—my
usual solution is to read the files in binary mode, and strip out any
`'\r'` by hand.  (I read into a class `Line` for this, which overloads
`operator>>` to call `getline` and then remove any trailing `'\r'`.)

Comment: Thanks. It is nothing wrong with fstream. I just wondered if somebody had the problem solved. I am going to implement your solution

Comment: A tip if you do and are using `boost::regex`: the implicit conversion of `Line` to `std::string` didn't seem to work for me when calling `boost::regex_match`, so I used `friend` to add global functions `regex_match(Line const&, boost::regex const&)` and `regex_match(Line const&, boost::smatch&, boost::regex const&)`.  These will then be found by ADL, so you can call them directly with the `Line` you just read.

Answer (score 0):

The two header files most appropriate to your needs are:

```
#include <fstream>
```

or

```
#include <cstdio>
```

`<fstream>` is generally preferred. If, as your comment indicates, `<fstream>` is not available, then `<cstdio>` should provide a useful alternative.

Specifically, you'll need to consider `fopen()` and `fscanf()`.

Comment: If `<fstream>` is not available, the question is incorrectly tagged C++, I think.

Comment: I can use fstream. Just didn't want to worry about having to manipulate the input too much to deal with platform formats